# DNS service crashing in Windows 10 with large HOSTS file

Tags: networking, windows-10, dns, hosts-file

I don't get why my Android device handles a large hosts file just fine, but if I try to use a similarly-sized file in Windows 10, the DNS Service starts using a massive amount of CPU and slows everything to a crawl. It gets so bad the system must be rebooted into safe mode just so the hosts file can be deleted.

I've heard of this problem in earlier versions of Windows, but I have fully updated Windows 10.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How big, is “large?”

Comment: ~5 - 6 MB or so...

Comment: Why are you using such a large hosts file?

Comment: Assuming you're using it for ad-blocking, consider setting up a personal DNS server instead. [Technitium DNS Server](https://technitium.com/dns/) or [MaraDNS](https://maradns.samiam.org/download.html) can do this for you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. My VPN application connects to their private DNS that is supposed to block ads and trackers, but there's no way I know of to see what or how much they are blocking. I suppose maybe there is a way to monitor the traffic on the VPN's virtual adapter to see what is getting through, but I'm not an expert in that.